# npm - install dependencies for a package in a different folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following directory structure:

```
/some_project
    source.js
    package.json
```

I would like to install the dependencies for some_project. 
I know I could cd into some_project and then run npm install

But I was wondering if it's possible without changing the directory ?
Something like

```
npm install some_project/package.json
```

Answer (score 438, accepted):

You can use the `npm install <folder>` variant with the `--prefix` option. In your scenario the folder and prefix will be the same:

```
npm --prefix ./some_project install ./some_project
```

Comment: This should really be marked as the correct answer, though I don't think the last `./some_project` argument is required

Comment: BTW, it creates empty `etc` folder in destination, it's a known bug https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/7249

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there any more clarity on whether the second `./some_project` is required?

Comment: the second `./some_project` is not required

Comment: Is it also possible to omit the `node_modules` folder completely in such a case? i.e. let's say I want to have these packages all in a folder called `/vendor` (and not `/vendor/node_modules`).

Comment: The second `some_project` is definitely required, at least on Windows.

Comment: I concur with Cameron's assertion that the second `some_project` is required - at least on an AppVeyor CI build

Comment: It still does not work. I have set the working directory by systemd, set `--prefix` and the install directory. npm still tries to install to /root/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on Windows 10. It installs the dependencies in the current directory and just puts a symlink in the subfolder.

Comment: Sometimes this does not create the node_modules/.bin directory.

Comment: What if the package.json file is in a folder and we want the command to be executed outside that folder `../`?

Comment: It is not exactly the same as `npm install` in the project directory, because of the symbolic links.

Answer (score 54):

**Update:** Since the `--prefix` option exists, I now vote for @coudy's answer to this question. Original answer below:

No, `npm` will always install in the current directory or, with `-g`, in the system wide node_modules. You can kind of accomplish this with a subshell though, which won't affect your current directory:

```
(cd some_project && npm install)
```

The parentheses makes it run in a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html).

Comment: This is eventually what I did - cd some_project && npm install. Thanks

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this for Windows?

Comment: @Meligy you can use `START /D "%my_dir%" /I /WAIT npm install`

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10 I couldn't get `--prefix` to work, so I had to `cd` and execute it.

```
cd PATH_TO_FOLDER && npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

On windows 10 using powershell the only thing that worked for me without all the problems and edge-cases mentioned in [this blog post](https://nerdymishka.com/blog/run-npm-install-in-a-different-directory/) was this

```sh
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "npm" -ArgumentList "install" -WorkingDirectory $web_dir
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a package.json in the root directory with the following contents:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "helloworldprojectname": "file:hello\\world"
    }
}
```

Then call this to install:

```
npm install --prefix ./hello/world
```

It installs `./hello/world/node_modules` using `./hello/world/package.json`.

(Windows 10, Node v10.16.0, npm 7.6.1)