# how to install with npm ALL the pakage.json dependency in a custom directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

Hy,
I want to install all the node dependency in another directory than the package.json.

I want this arborescence:

```
>package.json
>target-custom
> -> node_modules
> -> -> jasmine....
```

the issue is than when I run `npm install` I've this:(logic, but not what I want)

```
>package.json
>node_modules
> -> jasmine....
> target-custom (empty)
```

and when I run `npm install --prefix target` npm try to find a module called 'target'

any Idea ?

EDIT : I don't want the package.json be at the same level than the node_modules directory.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498403/npm-install-dependencies-for-a-package-in-a-different-folder

Comment: Did you try `npm install --prefix ./target` instead?

Comment: The issue is more than i don't want than the node_modules was put at the same level than the package.json." --prefix" do npm search the package.json in the ./target directory