# npm install not working with --prefix

Tags: node.js, npm

It seems that `npm install --prefix ./server` (with no args) is not working with `--prefix` flag. I just want to install all packages from package.json.
All I get after that command is:

> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/home/.../ProjectName/server/package.json'

All is fine when I put `npm install package_name -S --prefix ./server` for example. Then NPM will create `node_modules` in `server` and will add `package_name` package.

My files structure is:

```
ProjectName
|
+-- client
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- package.json
+-- server
|   +-- node_modules
+-- package.json
```

"Main" `package.json` contains all scripts (for Heroku and for me) and dependiencies for server. 
`client` is Angular2 app that's why it has own node_modules and package.json.

I use NPM 4.2.0. With version 5.0.3 (newest?) it seems that `--prefix` flag is not working at all.

EDIT #1

I've just discovered that I can solve my problem with `npm install` (which will install `node_modules` in my project folder) and then copy `node_modules` to `server/node_modules`. Without that copy `jasmine` throws errors during `tsc` build.

Now I have to have `node_modules` in main catalog and copy of them in `server`. That's so odd..

EDIT #2

According to `@Damian Lattenero` answer:

> npm --prefix ./server install ./ProjectName/package.json

or

> npm --prefix ProjectName/server install ./ProjectName/package.json

IS NOT WORKING and generates:

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install
>   "RecursiveNotebook3/package.json" as it is not a directory and is not
>   a file with a name ending in .tgz, .tar.gz or .tar

THIS WORKS:

> npm --prefix ProjectName/server install ./ProjectName

but generates:

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/home/tb/Projects/RecursiveNotebook3/server/package.json' npm notice
>   created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
>   npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/
>   tb/Projects/RecursiveNotebook3/server/package.json'

and

`package-lock.json` next to `node_modules`

and

empty `etc` catalog next to `node_modules`

and

There are some problems with build (`tsc -p server`) with mongodb package.

Comment: tBlabs and the second one didn't work also? that's odd because it is looking for the package json in the server folder?  I made an edit for the first and the second one

Comment: Hey tBlas! put your solution as an answer, is a good practice in this site ;)

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
npm --prefix ./server install ./ProjectName/package.json
```

or

```
npm install --prefix ./server ./ProjectName/package.json
```

Also, to understand better what the --prefix do, you can check this two answers:

[How to npm install to a specified directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory)

[npm - install dependencies for a package in a different folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498403/npm-install-dependencies-for-a-package-in-a-different-folder)

Comment: First option seems to work but dependently of params I get mass of strange errors. I will list them soon.

Comment: @tBlabs mmm I see, I think that is for a new question, the original one I think is solved, don't you?

Comment: @tBlabs maybe is confusing if you add all in the same question, the original one is one step forward, maybe the other problems you should ask in a new one, I will glad check it with you

Comment: I will post new question then. Thank You for help. I'm still checking every combination of Your answer cause very strange things happening here..

Answer (score 3):

Works for me

```
npm install --prefix ./server ./server
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the newest version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS), I encountered the same problem with `npm install`. I also got an `ENOENT` error, indicating that `npm` cannot find the necessary files.

When I installed `nodejs-legacy`, as shown here under:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

`npm` subsequently compiled fine, and my Angular application deployed as it should.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-legacy : Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Do I need `node` or `nodejs` package?

Comment: The versions I run with under Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, are as follows:
npm: 5.0.3.
node: 4.2.6

The nodejs package contains the nodejs binary as well as npm, 
so it is unnecessary to install npm separately. 
However, for some npm packages to run 
(such as those that require compiling code from source), 
you will need to install the build-essential package:
sudo apt-get install build-essential

Regarding nodejs-legacy:
This package contains a symlink for legacy Node.js code requiring
binary to be /usr/bin/node (not /usr/bin/nodejs as provided in Debian).

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

Those lines in `package.json` solves all my problems:

> "scripts": {
>
> ```
> "init": "npm i && mv ./node_modules ./server && sudo npm i typescript -g",
> ```

Strange but works...

Answer (score 0):

This part of my server package.json and all working fine:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "server": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "client": "npm start --prefix ../client",
    "client:install": "npm install --prefix ../client",
    "client:build": "npm run build --prefix ../client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will definitely work, I'm assuming your project root directory `package.json` also has dependencies.

```js
npm install && npm install --prefix ./server && npm install --prefix ./client
```

or user this script

```js
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix ./client",
    "install-all": "npm install && npm run client-install && npm run server-install",
    "server-install": "npm install --prefix ./server",
  },
```