# Can anyone help me with npm --prefix?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, prefix

I'm stuck with npm --prefix.
I'm trying to prefix my frontend folder so I can run both the backend and frontend at the same time.

I keep getting an error with the wrong pathway:
\backend\frontend/package.json.

Can anyone help me with that?

```
{
      "name": "backend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "User Authentication APP - MERN stack",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node backend/server.js",
        "server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
        "client": "npm start --prefix frontend ",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
      }
    }
```

Comment: this question might relate to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44467600

Comment: If you execute `npm start --prefix frontend` in the folder `\backend`, the relative prefix will cause npm to search the folder `\backend\frontend`. You can use an absolute path: `npm start --prefix \frontend`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "server": "npm run watch --prefix server",
  "client": "npm start --prefix client",
  "watch": "npm run server & npm run client"
}
```

Then run `npm run watch`