# Running npm install in another directory through node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to run  `npm i` in another directory from my node.js application. The reason for this is because there is a child process that is spawned in that directory. The parent app is on user's systems, so they cannot be expected to run `npm i` when new updates are pushed. I can copy the package.json to each directory where child processes could run, so that running install manually there would install the needed dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - install dependencies for a package in a different folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498403/npm-install-dependencies-for-a-package-in-a-different-folder)

Comment: @MarwanAmireh that is for installing via command line. I need to be able to do it programmatically through code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting something like this?

```
var cwd = __dirname;

var Proc = require ("child_process").exec (
    "npm i", 
    {
        shell: "/bin/sh",
        stdio: [ 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
        cwd
    }
);

Proc.stdout.on ("data", function (data) {
    process.stdout.write (data.toString ());
});

Proc.stderr.on ('data', function (data) {
    process.stderr.write (data.toString ());
});

Proc.on ('close', (code) => {
    console.log (`close: ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: Close, this got on me on the right track. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working:

```
var Proc = child_process.exec ('npm i', {
            cwd: '/path/to/folder/to/run/in'
          }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {

          });
```